# Django allauth google extra_data

Tags: django, google-authentication, django-allauth

I've implemented google authentication using django-allauth, but I'd like to get additional data from the Google API about the user being authenticated.  The immediate issue is that the username is being populated as the Google user's first name rather than the account username; however, I'd like to know what I can get from the API and how.

I see in the [providers->openid section of allauth docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#openid) that a extra_data can be specified, but I can't find any documentation on if this can be done for google provider, and if so what extra data can be requested.

Answer (score 1):

After playing with the OAuth API, I found what I need to change is the scope which is in the [allauth google provider documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#google):

> By default, profile scope is required, and optionally email scope depending on whether or not SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL is enabled.